# Using typedef ClassName< > after class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, crypto++

I'm new in C++ world and I don't understand what's going on when using this structure :

```
template <typename T>
   class NameClass{
.........

};
typedef NameClass<CryptoPP::AES> CryptAES;
//!Typedef for the AES Encryption\Decryption
typedef NameClass<CryptoPP::Blowfish> CryptBlowFish;
//!Typedef for BlowFish Encryption\Decryption
```

Is there an explanation?

Comment: It means `NameClass` is a template, parametrised by the type of encryption it uses. `CryptAES` and `CryptBlowFish` are specialisations for specific encryption types. Your introductory book should cover templates in detail; but it's too large a subject to explain here.

Comment: I want please to understand more what did you mean by "template" can you give me a tutorial.
this is exactly the structure I have :

template <typename T>

class Crypt{
.........
.......

};
typedef Crypt<CryptoPP::AES> CryptAES;
 //!Typedef for the AES Encryption\Decryption
 typedef Crypt<CryptoPP::Blowfish> CryptBlowFish;
 //!Typedef for BlowFish Encryption\Decryption

Comment: @Mike - Stack Overflow welcomes enthusiast programmers. Also see [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users).

Comment: @jww: I'm sorry you read something unwelcoming into my comments; that wasn't my intention. A subject as large as generic programming needs a tutorial to cover it properly, and this isn't the site for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is very likely also

`template< classT >` or `template <typename T>` above `class NameClass` and this means NameClass is a template, parametrised by the type of encryption it uses, by `T`.

read about templates [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)).

typedef is a keyword in C++. It's purpose is to abbreviate complexed names. In your example

```
NameClass<CryptoPP::Blowfish>
```

can be used by a shorthand of `CryptBlowFish`

because it was typedefed as

```
typedef NameClass<CryptoPP::Blowfish> CryptBlowFish;
```

before. So

```
CryptBlowFish cbf;
```

is same as

```
NameClass<CryptoPP::Blowfish> cbf;
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef

Comment: thank you, that's what I know from C.
But now what's the difference between using CryptAES or CryptBlowFish ?

Comment: instead of writing same logic in NameClass for type CryptoPP::AES and for type CryptoPP::Blowfish you write one: a template with type T, next you instantiate a template with deifferent (above) types

Comment: It's clear. however there is nothing into my code that allow ClassName to distinguish between CryptAES and CryptBlowFish !!!

Comment: when you instantiate template classes objects like CryptBlowFish cb; CryptAes ca; compiler generates code for classes as if you had written two times the same code, once for first type, once for second type

Answer (score 2):

This means that `NameClass` is a *templatised class*, i.e. one which is polymorphic in its behaviour dependent on the template argument.

```
typedef NameClass<CryptoPP::AES> CryptAES;
```

In English, the above says "From now on in this scope, CryptAES is another name for NameClass when instantiated with CryptoPP::AES as its template argument".

Comment: Pedantic:  `NameClass` is a *class template*.

Comment: and how can my class istinguish between template: CryptAES and CryptBlowFish !!!

Comment: @SADOK.net Those aren't templates, they're classes like any other. You distinguish between them exactly in the same way as if they were written by hand.